# possible to get attributes of a model as values or values_list? django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I know that with `queryset` we can use`.values()` or `values_list()` to get the `fields / attributes` we want

But what if we already have the `class 'app.models.Sample'`

for example I know we can do something like

`a = A.objects.filter(id=1).values('name')`

but what if I have something like

```
b = B.objects.filter(id=2).first()
b.name = 'changes'
b.field = 'another field'
b.save()
return b.values('name')  # I know this does not work but is there something like this?
```

Just being curious and tried to google around but not sure if there's a wording for this so couldn't get much.

Comment: No `b` is an object now not a `queryset`.

Comment: Why do you need that? You can simply write `b.name` instead.

Comment: @Selcuk that's just one field to return but what if I want more fields to return? let's say I want to return both `('name', 'field')` and more if there are so I wouldn't have to do something like `{'name': b.name, 'field': b.field}`

Comment: Again, why do you need that? You already have the model instance. Use that instead of a partial dictionary.

Comment: @Selcuk really sorry but maybe it's my misunderstanding but then how can I assign more selective fields if not using `{'name': b.name, 'field': b.field}`?